# Keycloak - move realm to newer keycloak version with different server name

Tags: keycloak

There were problems with the transfer of realm from an older version of keylock (11) to a newer one (16).
After realm transfer from old (https://old_keycloak.example.com/auth) to new (https://new_keycloak.example.com/auth)
everything works without problems. But a problem arises if, for example, a user logged out yesterday in the standard way using the logout functionality and left the browser open for the night, the server name and the full path from the old keycloak are saved in the browser (https://old_keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?state=b23h3dfc016e54819f38b6cb1e5b0d29&scope=profile%20email&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2myapp.example.com%2Fapp&client_id=admin-cli), while the app that uses for authentication keycloak is already reconfigured to the new keycloak and when I try to login it gives me a token error.
Is it possible to make the user, when going to the address that is saved in his browser, receive a token from the new keycloak server, and if so, how?
A little about the environment
Keycloak services and applications started in (AWS ECS)
standing in front (AWS ALB)
Keycloak containers don't work in a cluster
Keycloak cache not exposed
Thanks in advance!

Tried redirect in ALB from older to newer keycloak - no luck
It's working with redirects when user enters credentials on saved from yesterday's URI, but after it system asking second time to enter credentials and allows to enter to myapp, but expected behavior after the first time the user enters credentials - the system will authenticate.